# Cryptmount-setup is not working

Tags: mount, disk-encryption, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

When I tried to set up encryption using cryptmount-setup, it just returns without any feedback. It did not even created the `crypto.fs` file. I ran the commands: `cryptmount nextcloud_data` and `cryptmount -l` to show that the creation of the target was clearly unsuccessful, as follows.

```
------------------------------
Your filing system is now ready to be built - this will involve:
 - Creating the directory "/media/nextcloud_data"
 - Creating a 2700000MB file, "/media/hdd_3tb/crypto.fs"
 - Adding an extra entry ("nextcloud_data") in /etc/cryptmount/cmtab
 - Creating a key-file ("/etc/cryptmount/nextcloud_data.key")
 - Creating an ext3 filingsystem on "/media/hdd_3tb/crypto.fs"
If you do not wish to proceed, no changes will be made to your system.

  Please confirm that you want to proceed (enter "yes")
  [no]: yes
Making mount-point (/media/nextcloud_data)... done
Creating filesystem container (/media/hdd_3tb/crypto.fs)...~ $
~ $
~ $
~ $ cryptmount nextcloud_data
    Target name "nextcloud_data" is not recognized
~ $ cryptmount -l
~ $
```

I already reduced the size of the crypto-file, to make sure that is not the problem. Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: Would you please care to expand in the question. not in comments, why the error that you have got in your own pasted text is not a valid feedback?

Comment: Was the `Creating filesystem container` command interrupted or die separately? It didn’t end the line on its own.

Comment: It died on it's own. The reason for the is that I tried to write to a partition as read-only, as you can see in my answer below. I just can't accept it as the solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cryptmount-setup tries to write to a partition that is mounted in read-only mode, that is why the command exits unexpectedly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/260462)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm new to StackExchange. However I'm not sure how to improve my answer. I'm the author of the question and discovered that I tried to write to a partition that is mounted in read only mode, that is why the cryptmount-setup tool exits.